# Where is Sequence object in SQL Server at manual screen

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I create a `Sequence` object in SQL Server 2012 by code (not manually).

Now I want to see it in Screen SQL Server (SQL Server Console)

Thank for all consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right under `Programmability > Sequences` in the Object Explorer window:

[image]